# Weird behaviour passing build-args to Dockerfile through docker-compose

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm facing a *strange* problem (or better: two different, weird problems) trying to pass `build-arg`s to my `Dockerfile` through `docker-compose up`.

### My files - initial setup

`Dockerfile`:

```
ARG  NODE_VERSION
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}

ARG NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN
RUN echo "=====> token ${NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN}"
... ... ...
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: ./myservice
      dockerfile: ../Dockerfile
      args:
        - NODE_VERSION=10.15.1-alpine
        - NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN
```

With this initial setup in place, I have the following behaviour (on Linux Mint 20, docker-compose version 1.26.2, build eefe0d31):

- running `docker build --build-arg NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN=xyz123` produces in output `=====> token xyz123`: the `NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN` arg flows to the `Dockerfile`
- running `docker-compose build --build-arg NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN=xyz123 myservice` produces in output `=====> token xyz123`: the `NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN` arg flows to the `Dockerfile`
- running `NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN=xyz123 docker-compose up myservice` produces in output `=====> token` : the `NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN` env arg should flow to the `Dockerfile` due to `- NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN` (according to https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args: *You can omit the value when specifying a build argument, in which case its value at build time is the value in the environment where Compose is running*) but it seems to not be available during build

### My files - reloaded

Simply changing my `docker-compose.yml` file to

```
version: '3'
services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: ./myservice
      args:
        - NODE_VERSION=10.15.1-alpine
        - NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN
      dockerfile: ../Dockerfile
```

seems to solve the problem: switching `args` and `dockerfile` entries in yml file *unlocks* the capability to pass environment variables to `Dockerfile` as `build-arg`s through `docker-compose up`, too. **Problem solved. Or not?**

### Changing OS, getting new problem

So, developers in my team use a bunch of different operating systems: Linux, Mac Os, and Windows, too.
Running the same commands on the same version (1.26.2) of `docker-compose` on *Windows 10 Professional 1909* we're getting the same problem we faced initially, both using the initial version of the `docker-compose.yml` file and using the version that works on Linux.
We tried passing env var from command line, setting them in the command prompt, setting them as system variables through GUI... we tried launching `docker-compose up` for `git-bash`, too, but we're not able to get the variable value in `Dockerfile`.

I googled a bit aaround but I've not found any reference to known bugs or limitation of the Windows version of `docker-compose`.

Anyone have any idea what the problem might be? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally, after some try-and-fail on different OSs and with different configurations, I ended up with an explanation of my problem - and therefore with a viable workaround, which allowed me to reach a satisfactory configuration for my `docker-compose-yml` file.

**Short answer**: it wasn't a matter of OSs nor env var passing nor order of `context` / `dockerfile` sections - it was a matter of clash between different services in my *compose* file.

**More in detail**: my `docker-compose.yml` file contained an additional service, too, whose job was to initialize the database the application was pointing to:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: ./myservice
      dockerfile: ../Dockerfile
      args:
        - NODE_VERSION=10.15.1-alpine
        - NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN
    depends_on:
      - persistence
      - db_initializer
    command: sh -c './wait-for localhost:5432 -- ./wait-for localhost:15672 -- npm run start:dev'
  persistence:
    # Setting up the DBMS here
  db_initializer:
    build:
      context: ./myservice
      dockerfile: ../Dockerfile
      args:
        - NODE_VERSION=10.15.1-alpine
    depends_on:
      - persistence
    command: sh -c './wait-for localhost:5432 -- ./wait-for localhost:15672 -- npm run db:migrate'
```

So, the problem was that I was configuring **two** services based on the same, self-build image, launching it with different commands (`npm run db:migrate` for the `db_initializer` service, `npm run start:dev` for the application service). Apparently *compose* took the configuration provided for the first initialized service (`db_initializer`, because `myservice` was dependant on it) and used that configuration for both services, ignoring the (different) `args` section I was providing for the second container: so I was able to solve (this time really!) the problem simply merging services declaration, including all `args` I needed:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: ./myservice
      dockerfile: ../Dockerfile
      args:
        - NODE_VERSION=10.15.1-alpine
        - NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN
    depends_on:
      - persistence
      - db_initializer
    command: sh -c './wait-for localhost:5432 -- ./wait-for localhost:15672 -- run db:migrate && npm run start:dev'
  persistence:
    # Setting up the DBMS here
```

So, after a bunch of months without collecting answers, I think it's time to share my experience, hoping it can help someone encountering this weird behaviour.